# Error when consuming OData service - There is a type mismatch between the client and the service

Tags: c#, odata

I'm trying to consume a OData V4-service. The service has this relevant metadata:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
    <edmx:DataServices>
        <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="Some.Name.Space">
            <EntityType Name="StatisticalProgram">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String"/>
                <Property Name="ShortName" Type="Edm.String"/>
                <Property Name="Deployed" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="CreatedBy" Type="Edm.String"/>
                <Property Name="CreatedDate" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="UpdateBy" Type="Edm.String"/>
                <Property Name="UpdatedDate" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset"/>
                <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false"/>
            </EntityType>
       // Other....
```

Which I'm trying to map to this model:

```
[DataServiceKey("Id")]
public class StatisticalProgram
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using Fiddler to sniff the request, and both the request and the response looks ok, but I get this error:

> There is a type mismatch between the client and the service. Type
>   '[Namespace].StatisticalProgram' is not an entity type, but the type in
>   the response payload represents an entity type. Please ensure that
>   types defined on the client match the data model of the service, or
>   update the service reference on the client.

Everything works great if I use another source, like [odata.org](http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/$metadata).

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
    <edmx:DataServices>
        <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="ODataDemo">
            <EntityType Name="Product">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="ID"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String"/>
                <Property Name="Description" Type="Edm.String"/>
                <Property Name="ReleaseDate" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="DiscontinuedDate" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset"/>
                <Property Name="Rating" Type="Edm.Int16" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="Price" Type="Edm.Double" Nullable="false"/>
                <NavigationProperty Name="Categories" Type="Collection(ODataDemo.Category)" Partner="Products"/>
                <NavigationProperty Name="Supplier" Type="ODataDemo.Supplier" Partner="Products"/>
                <NavigationProperty Name="ProductDetail" Type="ODataDemo.ProductDetail" Partner="Product"/>
            </EntityType>
            // Other
```

And map to this model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

My client class for consuming it looks like this:

```
public class MyClient<T> where T : class 
{
    private readonly Uri _uri;
    private readonly string _entitySetName;

    public MyClient(Uri uri, string entitySetName)
    {
        _uri = uri;
        _entitySetName = entitySetName;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Entities()
    {
        var context = new DataServiceContext(_uri, ODataProtocolVersion.V4);
        context.Format.LoadServiceModel = GenerateModel;

        DataServiceQuery<T> query = context.CreateQuery<T>(_entitySetName);
        return query;
    }

    private IEdmModel GenerateModel()
    {
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<T>(_entitySetName);
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

And I use it like this for `Product` (works great):

```
var uri = new Uri("http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc");
var myClient = new MyClient<Product>(uri, "Products");
var result = myClient.Entities().ToList();
```

Or like this for `StatisticalProgram` (doesn't work):

```
var uri = new Uri("http://mylocaluri.com");
var myClient = new MyClient<StatisticalProgram>(uri, "StatisticalPrograms");
var result = myClient.Entities().ToList();
```

I'm using

```
using System.Web.OData.Builder;
using Microsoft.OData.Client;
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;
```

So, to sum up. **It works great if I use odata.org, but not my local OData source.** I figure that it might be related to the `ID`-property, since it's a `guid`. Can that mess up the mapping? The local OData source works great if you only use it with Postman or a browser. So there seems to be some problems with the mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I used the wrong attribute for defining the `Id`-column.

It should be:

```
[global::Microsoft.OData.Client.Key("Id")]
```

So now my model looks like this and everything works fine!

```
[Microsoft.OData.Client.Key("Id")]
public class StatisticalProgram
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
}
```